# How can I configure vim to highlight a specified line?

Tags: vim, highlight

I wish to mark a line so that when I review my code then I'll be easily able to spot it for further changes.
Some editors have options to mark the line by simply clicking on the line number. (Perhaps np++)
Is there a way thru which I can achieve the same ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. Marker by highlighting a specific line:**

Set first the highlight group name and colors:

```sh
:hi MyLineHighl cterm=bold ctermfg=white ctermbg=darkred
```

and then choose which line (Ex: line 8):

```sh
:match MyLineHighl /\%8l/
```

**2. Marker by putting a sign:**

set the color of sign column

```sh
:hi SignColumn cterm=none ctermfg=darkred ctermbg=none
```

define the sign Group and its settings

```sh
:sign define markLine text=▶ texthl=SignColumn
```

Place a sign : Group *"markLine"* with id *"1"* in line *"8"* of buffer number *"1"*

```sh
:sign place 1 line=8 name=markLine buffer=1
```

---

For more:

[**`:help sign-commands`**](http://wwwcdf.pd.infn.it/vim/sign.html#sign-commands) [**`:help :match`**](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#match-highlight) [**`:help hi`**](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:highlight)